# JBOSS 7 Monitoring Tools

Tags: jboss, monitoring, apm

Any good suggestion for Monitoring JBOSS 7 in Production ? I would also like to configure alerts based on certain condition. Of course , It has to be Open source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard JConsole that comes with JBoss dependencies added. It's used to monitor your servers state and mbeans, it's very useful.

To test it on localhost start your server and then run the JConsole from your server/bin directory and select JBoss in the Local process selection.

To use it on "remote" server, start your server on "REMOTE_HOST" and then run JConsole from an JBoss/bin directory and connect with the followin string

service:jmx:jmx-remoting://REMOTE_HOST_NAME:9999 (or the port you use) and enter the username and password.

Secondly, for more detailed info of objects creation, memory leaks, CPU% (profiling) there is another one as:
http://jbossprofiler.jboss.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use free open source APM like scouter.
It shows very useful realtime performance information of every request.

And also you can set a threshold of resources and can make plugin for alerting to external.

https://github.com/scouter-project/scouter

JBoss7 need to set module option.

```
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=~~~,scouter
```